# Imacros inserted in js script is failing when I use a variable to represent frame number

Tags: javascript, imacros

The macro statement in line 15 in the JS loop doesn't seem to register to the extract statements. As it returns #EANF# with all three frame numbers, the loop cycles through ends at 17 and that is passed to POS_LOOP.
However if I comment out line 11(//), un-comment line 10, set loop start to 16(line 6) and end to 16(line 19). In other words by passing for-loop and forcing the frame to number 16 the extract returns $449,000(meaning I have correct frame number), passes the frame number to POST_LOOP macro. POST_LOOP proceeds to extract all info needed from page.
For a while I was getting this error message "BadParameter: expected F= as parameter 1, line 2 (Error code: -911)".
So I added line 6 and line 16 to force a number and set !errorignore to YES.
I have forced loop to print all variables to screen as well as PROMPTS in POST_LOOP. All alerts show the loop cycling through 15-17 and Frame_valid contains #EANF#.
PRE_LOOP gets me to web page, JS loop finds the "working" frame number and then passes that to POS_LOOP macro for the extraction.
Soooo why does it not work when I use a variable in the statement "FRAME F={{Frame_nb}}" + "\n"; ?

```
iimPlay('++AATEST_PRE_LOOP.iim');
//declarations
var framenumber;
var retcode;
var Frame_nb;
var fnb=(15*1);

var find_number =  "CODE:";
find_number += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
find_number += "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + "\n";
//find_number +=  "FRAME F=16" + "\n";
find_number +=  "FRAME F={{Frame_nb}}" + "\n";
find_number +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:High" + "\n";
find_number +=  "TAG POS=R1 TYPE=TD ATTR=ID:hiLP EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
for(; fnb <= 17; fnb++){
    alert(fnb);
    var Frame_nb = eval(fnb*1);
    retcode=iimPlay(find_number);
   var frame_valid = iimGetLastExtract(1);
   alert(iimGetLastExtract(1));
   alert(Frame_nb);
   alert(frame_valid);
   iimSet("framenumber",fnb);
    iimSet("RetCode",retcode);
    iimSet("extract",frame_valid);

   //if extract was frame number than save frame number and play rest of   macro

 if (frame_valid !== "#EANF#")
     {
     var framenumber=fnb;
     break;
 }

 }
iimPlay('++AATEST_POST_LOOP.iim');
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to place all your `iimSet`'s directly before calling the macro by means of the `iimPlay(...)` function.

Comment: That works. Thanks

Comment: Link final solution: http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=27529&p=74268#p74175